# How can I add a logout button to my UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar Controller which my other ViewControllers are nested in. I want to add a logout button which just triggers an alert and doesn't segue into another view controller. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the UITabBarControllerDelegate to be notified when the user attempts to show a tab. In this delegate method, you can return false and intercept to do what you want.

Here is that method:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

}
```